# Accessing Strings Values within Plist file Arrays?

Tags: iphone, arrays, string, plist

I've got a Plist file in my project that has a number of different arrays; each array is a different category which then contains additional arrays for individual questions. The problem I'm having is accessing the nodes and their values within these arrays.

*Code I'm using:*

```
-(IBAction)nextleft {

    if (questionCounter > 1) {
        questionCounter -= 1;
    }

    [self nextQuestion];

}

-(IBAction)nextright {

    if (questionCounter < 20) {
        questionCounter += 1;
    }

    [self nextQuestion];

}

-(void)nextQuestion {

    NSArray *pair;

    pair = [categories objectAtIndex:questionCounter]; 

    plistQuestion = [pair objectAtIndex:0];
    plistAnswer = [pair objectAtIndex:1];

    abbreviation.text = plistQuestion;

}
```

*My categories array is filled from my Plist file with this line;*

```
categories = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"questions.plist"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  create a class in which you have two instances of NSString (question & answer) which consist the value of question & answer.Create an array of category which consist of object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
NSArray *categories = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"questions.plist"];

for (NSArray *pair in categories)
{
    NSString *q = [pair objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *a = [pair objectAtIndex:1];

    // process q and a
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out! But just one question, I assume I can just treat the 'q' and 'a'  as standard strings now? If so how do I step through each question for example, how do I move from the first pair of 'question' and 'answer' to the next pair/question in the categories array.

Comment: @KarlDaniel that's what this code already does. This is a for-in loop.

Comment: I was just wondering how I would step to the next array if I was using a button?

Comment: Ah OK! I see then. Then use a counter for indexing the array, then increment the counter ach time the button is pressed and to the processing in the button's action.

Comment: Just in simple terms you mean like this? - NSString *q = [pair objectAtIndex://Incrementing Number//];

Comment: I've edited my question to display the code that I'm using. The integer 'questionCounter' is incremented.

Comment: @KarlDaniel I don't see 1. where you increment the counter 2. what the action selector of the button is.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add the full view so that you can see.

Comment: One button increases the counter to go to the next question and the other decreases so that it goes backwards. They both check to ensure that they don't got above or below 20, as that's how many questions I've set for now. They both call up the bit that I showed you earlier. Also don't worry about '[self bingsound];' that has nothing to do with the questions.

Comment: @KarlDaniel your algorithm is wrong, you misunderstood the example. As each question-answer array only contains two items, incrementing the counter further will throw an exception. You don't need the for-in loop, use `pair = [categories objectAtIndex:questionCounter]; q = [pair objectAtIndex:0];` etc. Also, don't re-read the plist upon every button touch, because it's an autoreleased array, you'll end up eating all the RAM. Also, really, please try to understand the example a bit and think logically and algorithmically.